# How to get all values when parameter is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query form where I need to fetch details from a custom table in MYSQL. If the parameter is left blank all records should be fetched. If there is a value entered in the parameter then records for that value should be fetched.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'xxx';
session_start();    
global $wpdb, $current_user; 
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$param_1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['param_1']);

 if (!empty($param_1)){
  $sql = "SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5
            FROM xxx
          WHERE column1='$param_1'";
   } else {
   $sql = 'SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5
             FROM xxx';
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

This works fine with one parameter. I will need to add more parameters and those could also be null.

For e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5
            FROM xxx
          WHERE column1='$param_1' AND column2='$param_2";
```

Either of these could be null. How do I take care of this in MYSQL?

My question  is what would be the best way to take care of this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just inverse your if check. If it's empty or null display everything, else display with parameters.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: is it possible to get both params together?

Comment: @DavidD'Lima check my answer

Comment: You build the where clause though PHP.

Comment: what is relation between `column1` and `$param_1`? is it like 1 is common between columns and variable and rest for 2,3,etc?

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly will take care of avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: @RahulMeshram yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep appending the query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5
       FROM xxx
       WHERE 1=1 ";

if(!empty($param1)){
 $sql.= "  and column1='$param1'";
}
if(!empty($param2)){
 $sql.= " and column2='$param2'";
}
if(!empty($param3)){
 $sql.= "  and column3='$param3'";
}
```

**Note:** Passing parameters like this would lead to SQL injection, use binding to pass parameters to avoid SQL Injection. [Here is a good read about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$username = 'test';
$password = 'xxx';
session_start();    
global $wpdb, $current_user; 
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$whereArr=[];
if(isset($_GET['param_1'])){
   $whereArr[]="column1=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['param_1']);
}

if(isset($_GET['param_2'])){
   $whereArr[]="column2=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['param_2']);
}

if(isset($_GET['param_3'])){
   $whereArr[]="column3=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['param_3']);
}

$whereStr='';
if(count($whereArr)>0){
      $whereStr="WHERE " . implode(" AND ",$whereArr);
}

  $sql = "SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5
            FROM xxx " . $whereStr;

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
?>
```

Check for each param in the above demonstrated, Put them in array.

Then check if array is isset or not, if isset create a where string and the append it to your query.

Even if no param is set your query will run without where clause.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RahulSingh in the solution provided by you, $whereArr is an array right? How do I append the second parameter to the array ? Coz now when the second parameter is getting added to the array the first parameter is not there.

Comment: Yes it is an array, are appending value like `$whereArr[]="str"` or you can use `array_push($whereArr,'str')`. For details use the below link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for optimization of your code,

```
$getArr = array_filter($_GET);
// checking sql injection
$getArr = array_map(function ($v) use ($conn) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $v);
}, $getArr);
$temp = [];
// fetching numbers for that key
foreach ($getArr as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$key] = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $key);
}
$str = '';
// creating condition for data fetched in get
array_walk($temp, function ($item, $key) use (&$str, $getArr) {
    $str .= " column$item = '" . $getArr[$key] . "' AND ";
});
// raw query
$sql = 'SELECT column1 ,column2,column3,column4,column5 FROM xxx';
// if not empty string
if (!empty($str)) {
    $sql .= rtrim($str,'AND ');
}
echo $sql;die;
```